# Connect two separate Surround Sound Speakers with one Laptop

Tags: sound, system

I have two separate *Logitech Z506 Surround Sound Speakers* (5:1) and wondering, is there a way to connect them together and make one system with two subs and 10 speakers? One of the idea is to use *audio Y splitter*...And would there be any disadvantages for connecting them together which could stop me for doing that.

Back of the sub connection:
[image]

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Disadvantages… yes, it would sound awful. No way you could phase-match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something from physically stopping you, no, a Y splitter will do the job (you will need on for each channel though). You can also get powered splitters which are not made for anything specific but will just give you 2 clean output from one input.

As mentioned it will sound terrible and that comes back to why you would do this in the first place. For what its worth More Speakers != Better System. Some people tend to think this as there is stereo, (quad channel if you remember that), 5.1, 7.1 and other more involved formats usually used in movie theaters. That being said a good set of stereo speakers will outshine 50 5.1 systems connected to the same output even if the group of 50 systems is louder.